# In Python with Pandas, I have a function to change the index of DataFrame. But, it also changes the index of the original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetimeindex

I have a following `analysis.py` file. The function `group_analysis` changes the datetime index of `df_input` by the `Count` column of `df_input`

```py
# analysis.py
import pandas as pd

def group_analysis(df_input):
    df_input.index = df_input.index - pd.to_timedelta(df_input.Count, unit = 'days')
    df_ouput = df_input.sort_index()

    return df_ouput

def test(df):
    df = df + 1
    return df
```

And I have a following dataframe.

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,14), index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods = 13, freq= 'D'), columns = ['Count'])
```

```
            Count
2020-01-01      1
2020-01-02      2
2020-01-03      3
2020-01-04      4
2020-01-05      5
2020-01-06      6
2020-01-07      7
2020-01-08      8
2020-01-09      9
2020-01-10     10
2020-01-11     11
2020-01-12     12
2020-01-13     13
```

When I run the following code,

```py
import analysis
y = analysis.group_analysis(x)
```

the datetime index of both x and y are changed (and so, `x.equals(y)` is `True`). Why `group_analysis` changes the both the input and output datetime index? And how can I make it to change only the datetime index of `y` (but not `x`)?

However, when running the following code, `x` does not change (so, `x.equals(y)` is `True`)

```
import analysis
y = analysis.test(x)
```

EDIT: analysis.test(df) is added.

Comment: Try `y = analysis.group_analysis(x.copy())`? This happens because you are passing reference of your original dataframe to the function. @david78

Comment: Thanks for the help:). I do not have this issue when another function changes only values of x, but not the datetime index of x. For example, def test(): df =df+1 return df. Is there a reason the issue happens only when a function changes the index of the dataframe?

Comment: The first line of your file assigns to the index which is a property of the input dataframe. Thus not creating a copy of the dataframe itself. When you do an addition it return a copy of the dataframe after addition. To demonstrate this, try using a dataframe function with inplace argument set to true. You'll notice the change. @david78

Comment: Thank you for the help. Please find the edited original posting, where I added a new function 'test(df)'. I am not clear why the issue is not found for 'test(df)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a dataframe to a function, it passes the dataframe reference. So, any in-place change that you do to the dataframe, It will reflect in the passed dataframe.

But in the case of your `test` function, the addition returns a copy of the dataframe in-memory. How do I know that? Just print the memory reference id of the variable before and after the operation.

```
>>> def test(df):
...     print(id(df))
...     df = df + 1
...     print(id(df))
...     return df
... 
>>> test(df)
139994174011920
139993943207568
```

Notice the change? This means its reference has been changed. Hence not affecting the original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!!. But I do not know how to figure out which returns a copy of dataframe and which does not. Is there a specific rule? The first line of 'group_analysis(df_input)' subtracts 'pd.to_timedelta(df_input.Count, unit = 'days')', but it does not returns a copy.

Comment: Why do you wanna know that? Python passes into function always as a reference. Unless you want the original dataframe changed, you pass a copy. Each pandas function behaves differently. As I said, you need think about references.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have many functions with dataframes as inputs. As I never thought about this issue in the past, my other functions were generated without considering it. So, I want to know what situations a function does not returns a copy to review my other functions. Again, many thanks.

Comment: We too had many dataframe transformation based functions. But we made a copy at start of the process.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is because when calling `group_analysis` you are not passing a copy of the dataframe to the function, but rather a reference to the original data in the memory of the computer. Therefore, if you modify the data behind it, the original data (which is the same) will also be modified.

For a very good explanation refer to https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/.

To prevent this create a copy of the data when you enter the function:

```
...
def group_analysis(df):
    df_input = df.copy()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:). I do not have this issue when another function changes only values of x, but not the datetime index of x. For example, def test(): df =df+1 return df. Is there a reason the issue happens only when a function changes the index of the dataframe?

Comment: I believe it depends on the type of the varibles. When using simple types, the calling variable is not modified. Not sure though what your example is, should `df` be a parameter of test?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Please find the edited original posting, where I added a new function 'test(df)'. I am not clear why the issue is not found for 'test(df)'